# Select distinct columns but include top 1 from another column in results, based on distinction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a product table of 6 columns. Products are of a type, and types are of a category.

I selected 4 columns where I use DISTINCT to retrieve a set of results....

```
SELECT DISTINCT category, type, catlong, typelong 
FROM products 
WHERE catlong = @getcatlong 
ORDER BY type
```

This gives me a listing of product types and their category names based on my querystringparameter.

Example...

```
 category            type              catlong            typelong
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Drink Cups       Big Drink Cups       drink-cups        big-drink-cups
Drink Cups       Med Drink Cups       drink-cups        med-drink-cups
Drink Cups       Small Drink Cups     drink-cups        small-drink-cups
```

In the same table we generated the above query from, there are also columns for productname, productpicfilename. There are several product pic filenames to each type and category and are all unique. I need rewrite the query to include the top 1 productpicfilename for each type.

Example...

```
 category            type              catlong            typelong         procuctfilename
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Drink Cups       Big Drink Cups       drink-cups        big-drink-cups     redsolocups.jpg
Drink Cups       Med Drink Cups       drink-cups        med-drink-cups     bluesipcups.jpg
Drink Cups       Small Drink Cups     drink-cups        small-drink-cups   pinkdixiecups.jpg
```

I am unsure how to approach this. I have tried multiple different types of queries but they either return undesired results or errors. I will modify the title to this page if needed. Thank you.

Comment: maybe with a subquery in the fields clause ?

Comment: Why do you use distinct in first place?

Comment: @Mono Inherited database and sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply switch to aggregation instead of DISTINCT:

```
SELECT category, type, catlong, typelong, MIN(procuctfilename)
FROM products 
WHERE catlong = @getcatlong 
GROUP BY category, type, catlong, typelong 
ORDER BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

```
SELECT category, type, catlong, typelong, MAX( procuctfilename ) AS procuctfilename 
FROM products 
WHERE catlong = @getcatlong 
ORDER BY category, type, catlong, typelong
```

An alternative way is to use [Window Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql):

```
SELECT category, type, catlong, typelong, procuctfilename
FROM
( SELECT category, type, catlong, typelong, procuctfilename,
    -- Split all rows into groups (same as GROUP BY) and calculate order within each group
    ROW_COUNT() OVER( PARTITION BY category, type, catlong, typelong ORDER BY procuctfilename ) AS TopRow
FROM products
WHERE catlong = @getcatlong ) AS TopRows
WHERE TopRow = 1 -- returns only the first row from each group
ORDER BY category, type, catlong, typelong
```

This query is essentially an "inline" version of the above `GROUP BY` query. The advantage of this approach is that all of the columns will always belong to the same row. This is valuable when, say, you want to also show `productname` that corresponds with `procuctfilename`.